# Posting JSON to WebAPI

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I have a need to post some JSON data to webAPI and save it to a database, now I have never used webAPI so I am on a complete learning curve here.

So far I have created a webAPI project and and a DB table to house the data in SQL, I have added the model via Entity Framework

i have created an APi controller called FormController

This is the JSON that will be posted

```
{
"msg": {
"params": {},
"payload": {},
"files": {
  "74277A30-5740-4102-A183-697382A4C240.json": {
    "mimeType": "application/json",
    "data": {
      "auto": [],
      "form": {
        "formId": "74277A30-5740-4102-A183-697382A4C240"
      },
      "fields": [
        {
          "@name": "Patient Name",
          "@type": "DataTypeText",
          "value": "Jane Doe"
        },
        {
          "@name": "Date",
          "@type": "DataTypeText",
          "value": "2016-06-08T12:00:00Z"
        },
        {
          "@name": "Hospital",
          "@type": "DataTypeText",
          "value": "Burwood Hospital"
        },
        {
          "@name": "Wing",
          "@type": "DataTypeText",
          "value": "North Wing"
        },
        {
          "@name": "Level",
          "@type": "DataTypeText",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "@name": "Bed",
          "@type": "DataTypeNumber",
          "value": "11"
        },
        {
          "@name": "Severity",
          "@type": "DataTypeList",
          "value": [
            "High"
          ]
        },
        {
          "@name": "Validation",
          "@type": "DataTypeList",
          "value": [
            "Checked Medical Chart",
            "Personally spoken to patient",
            "Patient is awake"
          ]
        },
        {
          "@name": "Requested by",
          "@type": "DataTypeText",
          "value": "Nice nurse"
        }
      ],
      "template": {
        "name": "Paul Demo App",
        "templateId": "f9f0d5e2-84cb-a345-c1d1-f374c22a40fc",
        "templateLink": ""
      },
      "version": "1.0"
    },
    "fieldName": "file",
    "originalName": "74277A30-5740-4102-A183-697382A4C240.json",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "size": 1725
  }
}
},
"node": "302df9b0-2dec-11e6-816e-2f924acaff65"
}
```

I require to get the data from within the "fields" section and then save that to my DB

Apologies if I am being vague here, just fire me comments and I will try to answer your questions

Comment: it's json. decode it to a native structure, then access the parts like you would any other native structure.

Answer (score 0):

Send this data as Post requests body. 
Use content type as application/json.
Accept this data into dynamic type of object.
serialize this object using newtonsoft.json.ConvertTo(........)
and send this serialized object to database's Nvarchar or varchar field.
it will work.